# Add item to a generic list of object of UI thread from background thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, c#-4.0, generic-list

here is what I'm wanting.

Currently I'm creating a program that is based on multithreading concept using `BackgroundWorker` in .net 4.0 Windows Forms & C#.

Please see the attached image. I've described my basic idea there...[image: Description]

Comment: Go take a look at the Reactive Framework from Microsoft. It is meant to handle situations exactly like this. It allows you to observe streams of objects from multiple threads. It's kind of like events joined with linq joined with tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it does exactly what you need - allows to call methods in the UI thread.